# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut lag in chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an overlay that should appear on top of everything by fading in after the user clicks on a button. I'm using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut for this. However, there is significant lag in chrome while doing so, while in Firefox the animations run smooth.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay_profile">
        <div class="overlay_contents">
            <div class="overlay_profile_info">
                <img src="images/avatars/1.gif" />
                <div class="overlay_profile_info_text_username">
                    Qub1
                </div>
                <div class="overlay_profile_info_text_other">
                    Level 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay_close">X</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay_shadow"></div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    right: 150px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #978470;
    border: 3px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000, inset 0 0 10px #6A5C4E;
}

.overlay_shadow {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu_arrow").add(".overlay_close").add(".overlay_shadow").click(function() {
        if($(".overlay").is(':visible')) {
            $(".overlay").add(".overlay_shadow").fadeOut("normal");
        } else {
            $(".overlay").add(".overlay_shadow").fadeIn("normal");
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea why chrome would be lagging? Is it the heavy use of CSS3?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't call that heavy CSS3 use.

Comment: Well some of the child elements have a lot of css3 formatting (not in my post) but I think that css won't really slow it down. However it could be a webkit problem since it only occurs in chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding these rules to your classes:

```
{
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
}
```

This forces/tricks Chrome to send the CSS3 operations to the GPU, which should speed it up.

I guess it's just because Chrome is a bit shy about what it transfers to the GPU unlike Firefox.

Comment: @Qub1 Read this for more information about this trick: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: Hmm although the animation is somewhat faster now, the shadow div doesn't appear. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Qub1 Try removing the rules from the shadow div, but keep it on everything else that moves.

Comment: When I remove the rules from the shadow div it appears again, however the lag is back as well. I think the problem is the transparent background (the rgb alpha channel).

Comment: Interestingly though, the shadow is 'there' as clicking where it used to be does trigger the click event.

Comment: I decided to remove the shadow div, since I couldn't get it to work. I've now simply increased the box shadow of the overlay div, this gives a similar effect. And thanks to your code the whole thing runs at full speed :)
Marking as solved.

Comment: @Qub1 Nice to know. I wonder why the shadow div is vanishing though.

Comment: For some reason, I was getting artifacts of elements that truly were removed or faded to 0. This fixed it!

Comment: Had the same issue, and was driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue and this kinda worked. It is very impressive appoach. Thank you very much.